# Cannot set the FormulaArray property of the range vba 2003

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to set the FormulaArray property of a range in vba 2003. I am doing it this way,

The code:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AM4:AM" & (rowNum - 2)).FormulaArray = "=IF(A4=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$4:A$" & (rowNum - 2) & ")=MONTH(A4),A$4:A$" & (rowNum - 2) & ",1E+99)),A4,"")"
```

It is returning me an error '1004':

```
Unable to set the FormulaArray Property of the range method.
```

Not sure what the problem is. I am using the Excel 2003. Need some guidance in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take `rowNum = 5` for testing purpose, your formula evaluates to

`=IF(A4=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$4:A$3)=MONTH(A4),A$4:A$3,1E+99)),A4,")`

Notice, you are missing a Double Quote in the end?

Try this

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("AM4:AM" & (rowNum - 2)).FormulaArray = _
                                                        "=IF(A4=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$4:A$" & _
                                                        (rowNum - 2) & _
                                                        ")=MONTH(A4),A$4:A$" & _
                                                        (rowNum - 2) & _
                                                        ",1E+99)),A4,"""")"
```

The above formula now evaluates to

`=IF(A4=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$4:A$3)=MONTH(A4),A$4:A$3,1E+99)),A4,"")`

**Edit**

> how to change such that A4 in the code is moving according to the row it is in? –

You can't increment rows in formula array like that. To achieve what you want, enter the formula only in cell `AM4` and then fill it down. See this example

```
rowNum = 8
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    .Range("AM4").FormulaArray = _
                                "=IF(A4=MIN(IF(MONTH(A$4:A$" & _
                                (rowNum - 2) & _
                                ")=MONTH(A4),A$4:A$" & _
                                (rowNum - 2) & _
                                ",1E+99)),A4,"""")"

    .Range("AM4:AM" & (rowNum - 2)).FillDown
End With
```

Comment: thanks, one more thing, how to change such that A4 in the code is moving according to the row it is in?

Comment: I have updated the above post. You may have to refresh the page to see it